# Объединить python(gui) и C++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, gui

У меня есть программа которая работает с файлами, все готово кроме интерфейса, я бы его спокойно могла бы доделать на C++, но сроки поджимают. Можно ли сделать на Python интерфейс, а на C++ функции? Ну как-нибудь из Python вызывать их?

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/

Comment: ctypes, cython.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предположим, у вас есть простой пример класса C ++, который вы хотите вызвать из питона, в файле с именем foo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    public:
        void bar(){
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Поскольку ctypes могут взаимодействовать только с функциями C, вам необходимо предоставить те, которые объявляют их как `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo){ foo->bar(); }
}
```

Теперь компилируем это в библиотеку:

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  foo.o
```

И, наконец, вам нужно написать свою оболочку(например, в fooWrapper.py):

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj)
```

Теперь все работает ;)

```
f = Foo()
f.bar() # and you will see "Hello" on the screen
```

<sub>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)</sub>

Comment: Хороший пример. Немного в сторону: есть предположение, что GUI для задач работы с ФС будет отдавать ей аргументы в виде строк. Так вот, было бы здорово, если в примере будет передача строки в `c++` код (ведь именно тут могут возникнуть определенные трудности).

Comment: @mkkik Дельный коммент. Ща шуток занят, а тут надо поэксперементировать ;)

Comment: На питоновской стороне там по сути только привести к байтам, обернуть в `create_string_buffer`. А вот на `c++` надо делать интерфейс `char* -> string`. Это если везде `utf8`, иначе все может быть куда сложнее.